# Is bash supposed to evaluate array index expressions for side-effects even when the indexing expression goes unused?

Tags: arrays, bash, language-lawyer, conditional-operator, side-effects

Weird thing I recently discovered: At least on my version of bash (4.2), it seems like the conditional operator does not evaluate the untaken path normally, but it does so for array indexing expressions. Example:

```
$ echo $i  # i initially unset

$ ((0?++i:0)); echo $i  # As expected, i is not touched when false branch taken, like any sane language

$ ((0?a[++i]:0)); echo $i  # But when untaken branch indexes, and indexing expression has side-effect... WTF?!?
1
$ ((0?a[++i]:0)); echo $i  # Continues building on each call...
2
```

This was quite surprising, to say the least. It feels `csh`-like in its inconsistency. Is this a bug in my particular version of bash, or is it required in some way due to the interaction of rules for arithmetic evaluation and/or array indexing (where array indexing itself already imposes arithmetic evaluation rules) in some spec more detailed than `man bash`? (or did I miss where this is required in the Bash man pages?)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with `bash 5.2.15`. The output is an empty line for each of your examples.

Comment: The behavior changes from version 4.3 to 4.4. With version 4.3 I can reproduce the behavior, with version 4.4 not anymore.

Comment: @Cyrus note that using `shopt -s compat43` or lower does not restore the side-effect.

Comment: @LéaGris: I used the original binaries this way: `docker run -it bash:4.3` and `docker run -it bash:4.4`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: Thanks for that! Turns out the tester for the code golf I was doing *is* using modernish bash (it's just my local shell that's ancient), so I could use my original preferred solution (conditional array-based indexing w/increment) instead of the weirder version based on hooking up `stdin` to a `<(...)` command and using `read` to get the value. (Saved me a whole five characters golfing) I'll happily accept you or Cyrus posting an answer of "it was a bug, fixed in 4.4" as an answer (bonus if you can find/link a tracker issue for this).

Comment: Just spent a few minutes going through [the Bash `CHANGES`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES) file, copying out all notes between `bash-4.3-release` and `bash-4.4-release`, and searching for `arith`, `conditional` and `array`. I see a lot of notes related to those, but none that explain how this got fixed. Might have been fixed as a side-effect of one of the other changes, or maybe someone forgot to add the note to the changelog...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a bug, which was fixed in Bash-4.4 patch 8.

Related links:

- [bash44-008](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4-patches/bash44-008)
- [In ((0? var: 0)), expressions stored in var are evaluated.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-11/msg00050.html)

Though, I don't have an explanation why `((0?++i:0))` isn't affected by this bug.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely it. They give other examples in there where some indirect expressions get evaluated, while others (very similar) do not, including the case of array indexing evaluation. Thanks!